# Move Attachment Script

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA Script that I have used to move attachments from emails into a folder for consumption by an SSIS package. However, what I want to do it alter the script so that it renames the Attachment as it saves it to the folder.

Here is the current Script.

```
Public Sub saveAttachmenttoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String

    saveFolder = "\\vswi-sql\DATABASES\DATAWAREHOUSE\UNIVERSAL_DW\CS\CS_IMPORTS"
        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName

            Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next

End Sub
```

I am not familiar with VBA enough to comfortably make the correction, but I have a feeling it's an alteration to the last few lines.

The attachment that is received is named "WORKBOOK_4X5OFXQG7.XLS", it is a broadcasted report from our Netweaver system. I want to save it as "HRIS_CS_Complaints.xls".

Comment: what should be the name after renaming?

Comment: Sorry, I left that out. I have edited the content above to include this.

Comment: DAX was faster, my answer would be the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the line

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
```

In your particular case:

```
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & "HRIS_CS_Complaints.xls"
```

Please note that this will save ALL your attachments under this file name, so I think you should at least add another variable suffix to this file name like the current timestamp, attachment index etc.

Comment: I changed the name and then assigned the script to a job. When I ran the job it did not move the attachment, any ideas? Do I need to restart Outlook first before this will work?